# Adicionar várias linhas com jQuery usando .text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou a fazer o projeto para a escola, estou na parte do chat e estou com uma dúvida. Na parte de enviar mensagens em jQuery:

```
 socket.on('newMessage', function(data){
     $chat.append(data.nick+' - ' + menssagem+ '<br/>' ); 
 });
```

Mas o problema é que o método `.append()` é vulneravel, porquê deixa injetar javascript e ate mesmo html.
Eu já tentei o método `.text()`, mas as mensagens aparecem uma em cima das outras.

Comment: agora, estava quase, mas sempre que eu por exemplo mandava 'a'
e na menssagem aseguir um 'b' ele acrescentava um 'a' à ultima menssagem

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que adicionar a mensagem nova após ao conteúdo que já existe.

Senão, sobrepõe mesmo.

Tenta isso abaixo. Se der errado, tira o parênteses do `text()`.

```
$chat.append($chat.text() + '<br/>' + data.nick+' - ' + menssagem+ '<br/>' );
```

Comment: E a palavra **mensagem** é com um S só, pelo amor de Deus... olha o nome dessa variável.